# Google MAP Places API donot return lat lang

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using google MAP Places API and Autocomplete functionality. Following is the  sample code

```
 this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.autocompleteElement.nativeElement,{
      componentRestrictions:{'country':'IN'},
      types:[]
    });
    // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
    // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
    // bounds option in the request.
    //this.autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
    this.autocomplete.setFields(
      ['address_components', 'geometry.location', 'icon']);


    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed',()=>{
      let place=this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
      if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        console.log("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
      }



    })
```

Whenever I am calling gePlace(), it returns only name attribute. Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get this information using the place_id.

Inside your if statement try this:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ 'placeId': place.place_id }, function (results, status)
{
    // return if there was a problem
    if (status !== 'OK') return;

    // get the co-ordinates
    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();

    var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
});
```